C# async function in Lambda
I have a fairly simple Lambda expression
var list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 };

var filteredList = list.Where(x => FilterList(x)).ToList();

private bool FilterList(int x)
{
  // Do something here
  return true/false;
}

Now the FilterList has been changed to async so I am trying
var list = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 };

var filteredList = list.Where(async x => {
  return await FilterList(x);
}).ToList();

private async Task<bool> FilterList(int x)
{
  // Do something here
  return true/false;
}

This gives an error
Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<int, bool>'. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task, none of which are convertible to 'Func<int, bool>'
What is the correct syntax for async lambda like this?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async
